# Even the same query is used different results return in different days

Tags: google-analytics

I’ve noticed there is some inconsistency of the data in GA, even the same query is used to generate the report in GA, different results return if the reports are generated in different days. For example, the report generated yesterday is different from the one generated today. Can anyone give me an explanation? Please feel free to send me an email if you need more detailed information

Comment: Please provide example queries and the results. This is a public question and answer site and all the information required to answer your question should be provided here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The issue is that the data generated in Google Analytics in different days is different even for the same data range. For example, on 10th of June, I went to the Average Session time section in GA and chose "Android data" and chose date range as 1June to 6th, it gave me "2.2" seconds as the average session time; I did the same thing on 11th of June and it game me "3.2" as the average session time and etc.  Does anyone know if it is a known issue of Google?